# How To Draw a circle using using CxImage in VC++

Tags: image, visual-c++

I have loaded and displayed an image using CxImage functionality. now i need to draw some default shapes like circles and rectangles and lines. There is no defined function in CxImage for these only Line function is available. With that have i drawn rectangle. But no idea on how to draw circle.

if not possible using CxImage then what are the other ways and how this can be made with CxImage complaint(ie: I dont want to rewrite my functions for Save, New, Load Etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw circle, you can have a look on *Bresenham Circle Algorithm*. Start with Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm, you will find nice simple C implementation and an optimized version. Adaptation to CxImage is straightforward.

Comment: But that just drwas the circle on top of the image. it cant be saved with the image.

Comment: @CodingMastero : you changed pixel color (with something like CxImage::SetPixelColor http://www.xdp.it/cximage/doc/doxy/html/group___pixel.html) according to Bresenham algo right ? Why can't you save the resulting image ?

Comment: the user drags over the image with mouse pointer pressed. the circle has to be drawn on this area